# SQL - Execute any "ALT" command in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find a way to run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to switch to SQLCMD mode via T-SQL command. The customer does not want to use PowerShell.

I have tried the following, but I am stuck. Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @smtp VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @smtp = CHAR(65) + CHAR(76) + CHAR(84) + CHAR(43) + CHAR(77) + CHAR(43) + CHAR(81) 
SELECT @smtp
EXEC(@smtp)
```

Comment: `Alt+M+Q` is not a valid SQL statement, and therefore `execute`...well, won't. Alt+Q+M is a keyboard combination from an IDE that implements the functionality to do something when that key combination is pressed. First find the SQL functionality that performs the "switch to SQMCMD", and then bind it to your IDE keyboard shortcut. There's no SQL command that you execute with the phrase `ALT+M+Q` that does anything at all, because TSQL has no keyboard.

Comment: No exactly sure if I understand what your asking. But I think what your looking for is in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx

Comment: This is a duplicate of the DBA SE question, ["Can I enable SQLCMD mode from inside a script?"](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/can-i-enable-sqlcmd-mode-from-inside-a-script).